# MetaData for nested model of closed objects

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, metadata

I would like to provide meta data to nested object,  the object in question is closed off to me so I cannot add the [Required] attribute directly.  I have added first level attributes but I cannot seem to get nested level properties with validation meta data.  Is this not supported in MVC3?

```
[MetadataType(typeof(Meta))]
public sealed class EditModel
{
    public Employee {get;set;}

    internal sealed class Meta
    {
        [Required]
        // this is not valid syntax but hopefully shows what I am after
        public object Employee.Username { get; set; }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> What am I missing?

[FluentValidation.NET](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) and its great [integration with ASP.NET MVC](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=mvc&referringTitle=Documentation). Another important thing that you are missing is view models.

Comment: Is what I am asking not possible within the confines of MVC 3, I cannot change my whole platform at this time over to a 3rd party framework.

Comment: No, it is possible. You could use view models. View models are classes that you specifically define for the requirements of a given view. You never pass your domain models to the views. This way you have total control of what attributes you can decorate your view models with.

Comment: The EditModel above is a ViewModel, are you suggesting that I also wrap Employee in another defined ViewModel?

Comment: Yes, that's what I am suggesting. Normally a *pure view model* should not reference any domain models.